# Suppose $X_i\sim \text{Geom}(q)$ for $i\geq 1$, and $N\sim \text{Geom}(p)$. Let $Y=\sum_{k=1}^N X_k$. Show that $Y\sim \text{Geom}(pq)$

Tags: probability

I know the moment generating of function of geometric RV with paramenter p is $$\frac{pe^t}{1-(1-p)e^t}$$
So I'm trying to show that the moment generating function of Y is $$\frac{pqe^t}{1-(1-pq)e^t}$$However, I'm stuck at the step where,$$E[e^{tY}]=E[E[e^{tY}|N]]=E[(\frac{qe^t}{1-(1-q)e^t})^{N+1}]$$
Any idea to get this into the desired form?

Comment: $Y=\sum_{k=0}^NX_k$ or $Y=\sum_{k=1}^NX_k$?

Comment: @Yuta I edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align*}
E[e^{tY}] & =E[E[e^{tY}|N]] \\
& =E\left[\left(\frac{qe^t}{1-(1-q)e^t}\right)^N\right] \\
& =\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{qe^t}{1-(1-q)e^t}\right)^n(1-p)^{n-1}p \\
& =\frac{p}{1-p}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{(1-p)qe^t}{1-(1-q)e^t}\right)^n \\
& =\frac{p}{1-p}\cdot\frac{\frac{(1-p)qe^t}{1-(1-q)e^t}}{1-\frac{(1-p)qe^t}{1-(1-q)e^t}} \\
& =\frac{p}{1-p}\cdot\frac{(1-p)qe^t}{1-(1-q)e^t-(1-p)qe^t} \\
& =\frac{pqe^t}{1-(1-pq)e^t} \\
\end{align*}
$$